# How to parse json value long character

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I will try to parse the string of JSON but there is a problem to parse 'long' character in JSON string.

JSON code is below

```
{ "valid": 1, "delta": 0, "time": 23755, "date": 200815, "fix": 2, "status": 1, "sats": 12, "lat": 37529922, "long": 126898053, "speed": 874, "heading": 0, "alt": 171300 }
```

I want to get lat and long value but I can't get value because Long character is keyword

My code is below

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string json = wc.DownloadString(sb.ToString());
    dynamic temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    Gps = new GpsInfo();
    Gps.latY = temp.lat;
    Gps.lonX = temp.long; //Error long type is keyword
    SettingGpsChart(Gps);
}
```

How can I parse json value long and lat?

Comment: Ad: look - company I work for have search engine too https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+json+keyword (better than one you  use :)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@` symbol:

```
Gps.lonX = temp.@long;
```

And cast to your type:

```
Gps.lonX = (long)temp.@long;
```